# How to use serenity js Attribute to assert if the element is disabled

Tags: serenity-js

I have the following DOM on the page

```
<button type="submit" ng-reflect-disabled="true" disabled="">
    Save &amp Exit
</button>
```

Also i have a (screen-play) component to target it's attribute

```
import {Attribute, Target} from "serenity-js/lib/serenity-protractor";
import {by} from "protractor";

export class myComponent {

    public static saveAndExit = Target.the('"Save & Exit" submit button')
        .located(by.buttonText("Save & Exit"));

    public static saveAndExitAttribute = Attribute.of(CreateClientComponent.saveAndExit);
}
```

All I want to do is to make sure that DOM has the **disabled** attribute flagged, but my following attempt in a step_definitain file is getting nowhere

```
this.Then(
    /^he should see "Save & Exit" button still is disabled$/,
    function(buttonText) {

        return expect(
            this.stage.theActorInTheSpotlight().toSee(CreateClientComponent.saveAndExitAttribute),
        ).to.equal("");
    });
```

Basiccaly i dont have enough undrestaing of how to target any attribute, using [the attribute's question](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/blob/master/packages/serenity-js/src/serenity-protractor/screenplay/questions/attribute.ts)

Also I didnt mange to find any use-case of it, any advice, hint would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track! You just need to tell Serenity/JS *which* attribute you're interested in.

The syntax of the `Attribute` question is `Attribute.of(target).called('attribute name')`, as per the [unit tests here](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/blob/1ee6a888a54a0a95f823aed248d5df28fa987ab5/packages/serenity-js/spec/cookbook/content.recipe.ts#L52).

So instead of saying:

```
import {Attribute, Target} from "serenity-js/lib/serenity-protractor";
import {by} from "protractor";

export class myComponent {

    public static saveAndExit = Target.the('"Save & Exit" submit button')
        .located(by.buttonText("Save & Exit"));

    public static saveAndExitAttribute = Attribute.of(CreateClientComponent.saveAndExit);
}
```

try this:

```
export class myComponent {

    public static saveAndExit = Target.the('"Save & Exit" submit button')
        .located(by.buttonText("Save & Exit"));
}
```

and then in your assertion:

```
return expect(       
   actor.toSee(
      Attribute.of(CreateClientComponent.saveAndExit).called('disabled')
   )
).to.eventually.equal('');
```

Or even better, using the task to [See](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/blob/master/packages/core/src/screenplay/interactions/see.ts):

```
return actor.attemptsTo(
  See.if(Attribute.of(CreateClientComponent.saveAndExit).called('disabled'), value => expect(value).to.eventually.equal('')
)
```

Which you can then extract into another task:

```
const CheckIfTheButtonIsDisabled = (button: Target) => Task.where(`#actor checks if the ${button} is disabled`,
      See.if(Attribute.of(button).called('disabled'), value => expect(value).to.eventually.equal('')
);
```

Which will simplify your assertion to:

```
return actor.attemptsTo(
  CheckIfTheButtonIsDisabled(CreateClientComponent.saveAndExit),
)
```

Hope this helps!

Jan